# iOS - Onboarding setup causing JWPlayer fullScreen button to load initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift, video, jwplayer, screen-rotation

I have a tab bar application (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3) with three tabs. When the app is first launched, the code checks UserDefaults to see if a user is logged in. If there is a user, the initial view controller (the first tab) is loaded. Otherwise, an onboarding screen is loaded for the user to log in, after which he/she will get to the first tab.

This is the code I used in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Set up onboarding screen
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc: UIViewController

    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    if !isUserLoggedIn {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboarding")
    } else {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

On itself, this works perfectly. The problem occurs later. Any of the tabs can segue to a screen where I have an instance of the JWPlayer for iOS which takes about the top third of the screen. If a video starts playing and I rotate the phone to landscape mode, the video goes fullScreen (this also happens if the user clicks on the fullScreen button). However, when the device is rotated back to portrait, instead of getting back the screen with the video player on the top third, I immediately see the initial view (that is, the contents of the first tab). The video keeps playing in the background but I can't see it. I can't get back to the video unless I rotate the device to landscape mode again. So, landscape I see my original video, portrait I get the initial view (first tab).

I tried many things, such as deleting chunks of code one at a time, monitoring viewDidDisappear, viewWillDisappear (for the video screen), none of which were triggered when the phone was rotated to portrait. I also monitored if the initial tab was somehow being selected, but this wasn't the case either.

Only when I deleted the onboarding code from app delegate did the video player work normally.

Is there anything in the onboarding code that could be making the video player display the initialViewController upon exiting fullScreen? Is there a different way I could write the onboarding code?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi cesarcarlos I am facing the same issue. Can you please help me on this. What I need to do?

Comment: Unfortunately I could never get it working so I had to remove the onboarding. I created a view controller for the onboarding screen instead of doing it in app delegate.

Comment: Thanks cesarcarlos

Comment: Actually I have a initial view controller and presenting an another view controller on it with JWPlayer and facing this problem to dismiss view controller when rotating landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I had to treat the onboarding screen as any other, with its own ViewController. Then inside the ViewController I wrote:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Check to see if user is logged in
    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    if isUserLoggedIn {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self)
        return
    }
}
```

No other way to fix it, unfortunately.